# Dynamically creating controls and cannot update them

Tags: c#, datagridview

so I'm creating labels based off data from a datagridview. It works fine when I clear the panel then redraw (which causes a user object leak and eventually leads to my application crashing)

But I cannot figure out a way to refresh the values without a panel.clear? I've tried refresh/invalidate/update/remove etc everything but nothing works. this is in the method that I call:

```
      panel1.Controls.Clear();
      panel2.Controls.Clear();
      panel1.Refresh();
      panel2.Refresh();



 progressLabels = new List<Label>();
  progressBar = new List<ProgressBar>();

 Label newLabel = new Label();
                Label lblLastName = new Label();

                ProgressBar progBar = new ProgressBar();
                newLabel.Text = firstNameVal.ToString();
                newLabel.Location = new Point(50, (i * 65));
                newLabel.Font = font;


                lblLastName.Text = lastNameVal.ToString();
                lblLastName.Location = new Point(newLabel.Width + 80, (newLabel.Top));
                lblLastName.Font = font;

                panel1.Controls.Remove(newLabel);
                panel1.Refresh();
                panel1.Controls.Add(lblLastName);
                panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
                panel1.Controls.Add(progBar);
```

**The Loop to iterate through the datagridview and populate labels**

```
for (i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value
             != null)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].
                        Cells[0].Value.ToString().Length != 0 && dataGridView1.Rows[i].
                        Cells[1].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                    {
                        firstNameVal = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                        lastNameVal = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                        percent = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

                    }
                }
```

It all works fine except for hte user object leak. Is there a way I can completely clear the objects instead of panel.clear or something?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your loop in the code that also is used? I see the `i` value in Point. (if possible) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN documentation for [Control.ControlCollection.Clear Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), I quote:

> Calling the Clear method does not remove control handles from memory.
>   You must explicitly call the Dispose method to avoid memory leaks.

Why don't you do the Dispose call?
Something like this:

```
for (int i = panel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
    panel1.Controls[i].Dispose();
```

Also on suggestion note, why can't you reuse the labels create and change their properties? I mean, if your controls are remaining constant inside the panel, just create an update method that would loop your controls in panel, get the labels out and update the properties rather than re-creating them again.

Using [Memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/) you can at least point to check whether there is a leak in adding controls. Usually it should not leak much if your controls range from 1 to 50. Also, if you want to avoid doing add/remove or update the records in UI, why don't you use a DataGridView to show the records? My personal opinion, I have used DataGridView for many data showcasing act. (If you wish there are plenty of tutorials out there for datagridview, you can see [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117021/How-to-Create-ProgressBar-Column-in-DataGridView))

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I've tested that code but my user Objects still seem to be climbing as soon as the labels etc get added?

Comment: @AlexP2014 okay, so how frequent are you adding the controls?

Comment: Would that work in my scenario though? As I may have less/more labels due to new records being added and records being removed

I'm adding them every minute.

Comment: So when you say less/more labels, are your labels count not constant? I mean to ask, do you know at a given point of time how many controls are there in your panel?

Comment: The label count isn't constant. They could go from 1 label to 30 labels, then back to 5 for example within an hour.

Comment: Could try and use http://memprofiler.com/ and check the leakage in your code? Is it because of the adding label dynamically? Because `Dispose()` is used to avoid the memory leaks.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I definitely think it is the adding labels, because whenever I just do a normal refresh or invalidate / update, no leakage but the controls just don't refresh.

Do you know of anything else that could cause the issue? OR a different approach potentially? Thankyou

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61725/discussion-between-learningneverstops-and-alexp2014).